# Identify the page to which it goes, within a webview

Tags: android, webview, identify

There is some method to identify in a webview, if the user clicks link 1 or link 2, and do something about it, for example within the webview if the user goes to page 2 show an image, or if you go to link 3 display this page and the application displays a text, in short, detect in which page the user is located within the webview and make an action about it, any ideas and/or examples of this type of activities? Really would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the link of the current page, so that you can perform the action

```
wbView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
       wbView.loadUrl("Url");

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            Log.v("uuuurl",url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, i'm doing it, but i want to identificate, if of the page 1 goes to page two or three through a link, and do a different action as the case to go to link 2 or 3.